# Convert date to given format from input

Tags: php, wordpress, date, timestamp

I need to convert a given date already stored in database to a certain format. I have been trying to google it but can't get it working.

*The Format as Input*: `d-j-Y` `( 06-16-2015 )`

*The Format to be converted in:* `F j, Y`  `(June 16, 2015)`

**The code I have been trying to convert,**

```
$date               = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'timeline_event_date', true );
$old_date           = date('d-j-Y', $date);
$old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
$new_date           = date('F j, Y', $old_date_timestamp);
```

**`var_dump(s)`:**

- `var_dump` for `$date`: `string(10) "06-16-2015"`
- `var_dump` for `$old_date`: `string(9) "01-1-1970"`
- `var_dump` for `$new_date`: `string(15) "January 1, 1970"`

**EDIT For The Duplicate Question**

The duplicate question you marked has the solution to fix this, but I feel this is a good test case for all of WordPress users who are having the same issue ..

Comment: All keys in WordPress meta data are stored as `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, in case someone needs it:

```
$date   = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'timeline_event_date', true );

$parsed = date_parse_from_format('n-d-Y', $date);

$old_date_timestamp = mktime(
        $parsed['hour'], 
        $parsed['minute'], 
        $parsed['second'], 
        $parsed['month'], 
        $parsed['day'], 
        $parsed['year']
);

$new_date = date('F j, Y', $old_date_timestamp);
```

Basically, this code converts `string` to proper date format.